# Can Gentiles Perform a Vasectomy?

Tags: gentiles, sexuality, pru-urvu

Can Gentiles perform a vasectomy once there is an understanding that they are not obligated to have children? If it is prohibited, what principle is it linked to? If vasectomy is prohibited, would freezing the semen and having children later nullify any punishment from the divine court or is the principle of having children naturally?

Comment: Are you asking about performing one or receiving one?

Comment: To receive. Not on me but if the Gentiles are permitted to perform this surgery on themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Found this online.........

https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/castration-sterilization-to-humans-and-animals/

Rav Chidka and Tana Divei Menashe in Sanhedrin 56b and in Bava Metzia 90a rule that one of the seven Nohadite laws is not to castrate [they remove the prohibition of Birchas Hashem and replace it with Sirus], and hence gentiles are commanded against castrating, just like they are commanded to follow the other Nohadite laws; However, the Tana Kama in Sanhedrin ibid rules that gentiles are not commanded against castrating. [As they list Birchas Hashem as one of the seven Nohadite laws, which thus excludes the prohibition of Sirus from being included.]